# Java: Why can i read a private attribute?

Tags: java, attributes, modifier

this might be a dumb question, but I was wondering why I can still read the radius and age attributes even though I used the private modifier. I thought that I would neither be able to read nor instantiate such modified attributes without using getters and setters.

```
public class Test {
    private int radius = 3;
    private int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test a = new Test();
        System.out.println(a.radius);
        System.out.println(a.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you’re reading them from *inside* the class. `main` is inside the scope of `Test`, even if it’s static.

Comment: Private members are available to the class to use and not for other classes.

Answer (score 1):

`private` only means these variables can't be directly accessed from **outside** the class. All methods **inside** the class can use the variable freely.

Answer (score 0):

Methods, variables, and constructors that are declared private can only be accessed within the declared class itself.

Private access modifier is the most restrictive access level. Variables that are declared private can be accessed outside the class, if public getter methods are present in the class.

Using the private modifier is the main way that an object encapsulates itself and hides data from the outside world.